# Deploying Shiny App based on trigger event

Tags: r, shiny, deployment, triggers, shinyapps

I have a dashboard connected to a data source via the google drive and my visualization works great locally and on shinyapps. I was wondering if there was a way to invoke certain "triggers" to run my code. In this instance, if the connected data source is updated, deploy the app.

It can also be less direct because we are using Azure Logic Apps so if theres perhaps a way to ping myself locally to run my script that also works.